# Test react component with Router and createMemoryHistory gives warning

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jestjs

When writing my tests for components that depends on routing like this:

```
const history = createMemoryHistory('/');
const wrapper = mount(<App history={history} />);
```

I get loads of warnings like this:

```
(node:24823) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 3): TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined
(node:24823) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:24823) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 4): TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined
```

I don't know how to proceed to eliminate them. May anyone help?

My app passes this `history` property forward to `<Router />`